# Mouse intermittently freezes when laptop is closed but monitors connected via DisplayPort

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, mouse, displayport

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 on an HP Envy 17 3D. I like to use extra monitors so I connected one via the DisplayPort port. I plan to add a second external monitor later, and use this laptop as a desktop replacement.

Because I don't need the actual built-in laptop screen when I'm at my desk, I wish to close the laptop while the mouse, keyboard, and external monitor is still connected.

This partially works - the monitor still stays on and the mouse still moves. However, every ~5 seconds the mouse stops working for about a half second and then resumes. So as I move my mouse across the screen, it halts in one place while and then keeps going for a bit and then halts - on and on. I've tried all of the USB ports.

Here's the graphics card information from `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 168a
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at c2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
        Expansion ROM at c2440000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

My goal is to be able to connect two monitors to the two DisplayPort ports, close the laptop, and use this set up just like I would a desktop. How do I get rid of this annoying mouse-lagging that makes everything unusable?

EDIT:
As I've just found out, it really has nothing to do with closing the lid itself.
Here's what my display config looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dstpi.jpg[image: Here's what my display config looks like]

When I select "Laptop" and turn that display off (while keeping the lid open), the same problem occurs. The internal display goes black, as expected, but after this the mouse and keyboard begin to halt every ~5 seconds.

Comment: Did you [set Ubuntu to "Do Nothing" when you close the lid](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)?

Comment: @techie007 Just tried this, it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the official drivers for linux x86_64 from AMD. After this, the problem stopped happening.
Though, I would like to note that my laptop will no longer boot when an external display is connected. I must first disconnect the display, let it boot, and then re-connect it.